# how can i compare a user defined variable with character in if else statement in C?

Tags: c

In if  else condition I want to compare user input variable with character so that if any character is typed by user it can be detected. How can I do this?

if ( i == (any character typed by user) )

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share what you had and did not work for you? Also, please be more specific with the flow you want to have. Do you want to detect every key stroke or you want to read into a buffer and then process the string?

Comment: How is the user entering data?  Are you comparing individual characters or strings?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details?

You would want to use a function such as `memcmp` or `strcmp` depending on your situation if you want to compare a sequence of characters.

See the useful documentation for [memcmp](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/) and [strcmp](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

If you want to compare live input of a character this should suffice

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char checkVariable = 'a';
    if (getc(stdin) == checkVariable) // Grabs first character from user input
        printf("Correct");
    else
        printf("Incorrect");
}
```

Comment: Please note that `strcmp` and `memcmp` are functions that compare sequences of characters or bytes. The question author asked for plain character comparison, if I understood corectly

Comment: Answer changed to reflect your comment. Thank you for the input!

Comment: That's the exact answer I suspect the author needs. I was thinking about `getc` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char c;
scanf("%c", &c);
if(c == 'A')
{
    printf("'A' is pressed");
}
else
    printf("Not 'A' is pressed");
}
```

Comment: actually I want a program so that I can if I write any character it is detected by if condition not only specific one like 'A'.

Comment: You can try this, if(isalpha(c)) @Mohit